# In Elixir/Phoenix, after template change, "cannot define module MyApp.PageView because it is currently being defined"

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I just changed an image path in a template in my Phoenix app and reloaded the page. This error message appeared in the browser:

```
CompilationError at GET /
Showing console output

== Compilation error on file web/views/page_view.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/views/page_view.ex:1: cannot define module Youli.PageView because it is currently being defined in web/views/page_view.ex:1
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:657: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
```

Running `mix compile` in the terminal made the problem go away, but isn't there some way to skip that step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in Elixir that has been fixed in Elixir v1.0.3.

Comment: I'm on Elixir `1.10.2` and this happens to me all the time.

`{:phoenix, "~> 1.4.16"}, {:phoenix_live_view, "~> 0.12.0"},      {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.11"}, {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.2", only: :dev}`

Comment: I also have this problem with `1.10.3`

Comment: v1.10 here, same problem. Not on Phoenix though. Just pure Elixir.