# Elixir 1.10.2 / Phoenix 1.5 after template change, often get "cannot define module ... because it is currently being defined in" (Mid 2020)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, slime

I still frequently get this error using the latest elixir/phoenix, so this is not the same as the error fixed in Elixir v1.0.3 and described here: [In Elixir/Phoenix, after template change, "cannot define module MyApp.PageView because it is currently being defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28912614/in-elixir-phoenix-after-template-change-cannot-define-module-myapp-pageview-b)

Running mix.compile in another terminal reveals the error, in this case, it was a slime template.:

```
** (TokenMissingError) lib/tealdog_web/templates/workspace/_row_controls_center.html.sleex:30: missing terminator: " (for string starting at line 27)
    (eex 1.10.2) lib/eex/compiler.ex:45: EEx.Compiler.generate_buffer/4
    (phoenix 1.5.4) lib/phoenix/template.ex:351: Phoenix.Template.compile/3
    (phoenix 1.5.4) lib/phoenix/template.ex:166: anonymous fn/4 in Phoenix.Template."MACRO-__before_compile__"/2
    (elixir 1.10.2) lib/enum.ex:2111: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
    (phoenix 1.5.4) expanding macro: Phoenix.Template.__before_compile__/1
    lib/tealdog_web/views/workspace_view.ex:1: TealdogWeb.WorkspaceView (module)
    (elixir 1.10.2) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:304: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/7
```

I'm not sure if this is specific to slime or not.  I didn't see any issues in the `slime-lang`'s issue list on GitHub (https://github.com/slime-lang/phoenix_slime/issues).

This seems to be a fairly common problem that is NOT solved in many cases and is hard to repro.  Does anyone have a fix?

```
  defp deps do
    [{:phoenix, "~> 1.5.3"},
      ...
      {:phoenix_slime, "~> 0.13.1"},
      ...]
```

Elixir version 1.10.2, OPT 21

```
elixir -v
Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.3.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:12:12] [ds:12:12:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

Elixir 1.10.2 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 21)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error happens mostly in two cases:

- there are dynamic cross-references between modules that cannot be resolved by compiler’s dependency graph, or
- some library/code creates the module(s) on the fly with [`Module.create/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html?#create/3) and is written not accurately enough to handle this

In such cases the order of files to compile is random and hence you experience this flaky behaviour. The only fix I could suggest would be to explicitly require some other module from problematic module to ensure the compilation order (with `alias` or like.)

Also, using [`boundary`](https://github.com/sasa1977/boundary) library might make the error source detection easier.